# Entity with two FK to the same entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am making an appointment system and have some problem with mysql structure and model structure. There will be two kinds of users (at least): customer and provider. Customers will be making appointments for choosen work with available provider for that work. Providers will be able to add themself to choosen work to be available for customers. Finally there will be appointment with start date, end date and foreign keys to customer_id and provider_id (from table users) and work_id (from table works). So in appointments table I will have 2 FK to the same entity (User), but one will be customer and one will be provider. 
What mapping should have user and customer fields in Appointment class and field appointments in User class? I will differentiate users by the role with users_role table.
Is it even possible to do it with only one common table for users?

here is the link to mysql schema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFn8O.png

Appointment.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="appointments")
public class Appointment extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name="start")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime start;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm")
    @Column(name="end")
    private LocalDateTime end;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="work_id")
    private Work work;

    ??????
    private User customer; 

    ??????
    private User provider;
}
```

User.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    ??????
    private List<Appointment> appointments;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="works_providers", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_user"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_work"))
    private List<Work> works;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify column names:

```
@OneToMany    
@JoinColumn(name = "first_column")
private User customer; 

@OneToMany    
@JoinColumn(name = "second_column")
private User user;
```

on parent sidy refer to the child:

```
@ManyToOne(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Appointment> appointmentsByUser;

@ManyToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
private List<Appointment> appointmentsByProvider;
```

Comment: Yeah, I know but the problem is with field appointments in User.class   It should be mapped by what? To get all the appointments for the customer if it is customer or to get all the appointments for provider if it is provider